# Class global name is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have created a simple python class, the code is shown below.

```
class Solution38:
    def countAndSay(self, n):
        self.n = n
        a[0] = 1
        for t in range(n):
            s = str(a[t])
            l = len(s)
            b = '1'
            c = 0
            f = []
            for d in range(l):
                if s[d] == b:
                    c = c+1
                else:
                    m = str(c)+str(b)
                    b = s[d]
                    c = 1
                    f = f+str(m)
        return f



solution = Solution38()
print solution.countAndSay(4)
```

when I was trying to run it, it says "global name 'a' is not defined".
also, when I changed `a[0]` to `self.a[0]`, another error pop up, says "Solution38 instance has no attribute 'a'".

Can anyone help me about this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `a` supposed to be? Also you don't need a class, just use a function.

Comment: Where is `a` defined? Is it a dictionary or a list?

Comment: thanks, I have added "a = {}", but another error says 'int' object is not iterable...

Comment: @younger it's because your code tries to iterate over `n` that is an integer. You should provide more information about what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @Vincent https://leetcode.com/problems/count-and-say/

Comment: @Vincent, thanks, I have changed "for t in n:" and "for d in l:" to "for t in range(n):" and "for d in range(l):", the previous errors have solved, but a new error in line "s = str(a[t])" occurs, the error is KeyError: 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
a = 5
```

creates the variable `a`. Something like

```
a[0]
```

**uses** the variable `a`, so it must already exist. And in your case, it doesn't.

Comment: I don't quite understand... how could I make this variable exist?

Comment: Read my first sentence again.

Comment: thanks, I have added "a = {}", but another error says 'int' object is not iterable...

Comment: Well yeah, `n` is a single number. How do you iterate over `3`? What does that even mean? You probably want to iterate over a **range**, like `range(n)`. Maybe you should start with Solution1.

Comment: thanks, I have changed "for t in n:" and "for d in l:" to "for t in range(n):" and "for d in range(l):", the previous errors have solved, but a new error in line "s = str(a[t])" occurs, the error is KeyError: 1

Comment: I saw you added the `a = {}` in the question code. Don't do that. It makes your question and all answers a lie. Your question is about a variable not being defined. Don't change the question to something completely different.

Comment: thanks, I see what's wrong here, I do really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `a[0] = 1` is different from `b = 1`. You can directly assign `1` to name `b`, but you have to access the first member of `a` before giving it a new value, thus `a` has to exist before updating.

```
self.n = n
for t in n:
```

This is wrong. I guess what you're trying to achieve is

```
for t in range(n):
```

Plz correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: thanks, I have added "a = {}", but another error says 'int' object is not iterable.., line 'for t in n:'

Comment: thanks, I have changed "for t in n:" and "for d in l:" to "for t in range(n):" and "for d in range(l):", the previous errors have solved, but a new error in line "s = str(a[t])" occurs, the error is KeyError: 1

Comment: @younger I really think you should step through the basic knowledge of Python. your `a` does not have key `1` thus `a[1]` gives you `KeyError`.

Answer (score 1):

"Solution38 instance has no attribute 'a'" - This error would occur because you declared a = [] as a class variable and not an instance variable. Changing a[0] to self.a[0] later wouldn't fix this. You would need to declare it as self.a= {} from the very beginning.
https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions

"but another error says 'int' ob is not iterable.., line 'for t in n:"
Here your error is simply telling you you can't loop through a single int. You are passing in n=4, how would t loop through that? 'For t in 4' doesn't make sense. You should look at the range() function in python

```
for t in range(n):
   :
   :
```

- I'm not too sure exactly what you are trying to do here but this should help you iterate four times if that's what you're looking for.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

Read up on both of this and look at some examples! They'll be very useful if you want to continue to code.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `a` by calling `a=[]` before using it in `a[0]=1` because `a[0]` tries to get the zeroth element from the iterable `a`. It is however reommended to just initialize it with an element:

```
def countAndSay(self, n):
    self.n = n
    a = [1]
    for t in n:
        s = str(a[t])
        l = len(s)
        b = '1'
        c = 0
        f = []
        for d in l:
            if s[d] == b:
                c = c+1
            else:
                m = str(c)+str(b)
                b = s[d]
                c = 1
                f = f+str(m)
    return f
```

Comment: hanks, I have added "a = {}", but another error says 'int' object is not iterable.., line 'for t in n:'

Comment: I have to admit I don't understand your code at all, what are you trying to achieve?